# unittesting sqlalchemy BinaryExpressions

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mocking, python-unittest

I'm writing some unittests for some code that uses SQLAlchemy. I want to test `filter` calls, but it seems that SQLAlchemy `BinaryExpression` objects created with the same arguments don't compare equal:

```
AssertionError: Expected call: filter(<sqlalchemy.sql.elements.BinaryExpression object at 0x1037607d0>)
Actual call: filter(<sqlalchemy.sql.elements.BinaryExpression object at 0x1037590d0>)
```

I suppose I can cast them both to strings and compare those, but that seems hacky, and I'd really rather not be forced to try to debug string comparisons if I don't have to. Are there any better/more-structured ways to compare `BinaryExpression`s in unittests?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you can use [compare](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.BinaryExpression.compare) method

```
>>> binary_expression1 = Table.id==1
>>> binary_expression1
<sqlalchemy.sql.elements.BinaryExpression object at 0x7ff0b7c6f7d0>
>>> binary_expression2 = Table.id==1
>>> binary_expression2
<sqlalchemy.sql.elements.BinaryExpression object at 0x7ff0b7c4a490>
>>> binary_expression1.compare(binary_expression2)
True
```